# Searching for popular tags without tag wikis

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki

I feel as if there are popular tags without tag wikis, out there to be found. Searching for such tags is a pain as I have to scan the entire page, and often the ones in need of tag wikis are not on the first few pages.

Can we have either a method to search for popular tags without tag wikis (as part of the site without use of the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/introducing-stack-exchange-data-explorer/) (SEDE)), or possibly a method to request tag wikis for tags that *really* need them (over a certain percentile rank by popularity, or reputation points requirement to request such tag wikis)?

It can help generate useful tag wikis where they are truly needed.

Comment: Related support question: [Search all tags with no tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165889/335251)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would also generate a lot of crap tag wiki suggestions from users who want the badge and can now easily find all the tags without wikis. Users who don't actually know anything about the tag or how it's used will go briefly research it on Google to get a general idea and then suggest a crap wiki that doesn't really explain anything or help anyone use the tag properly. Even worse, **they'll get approved** because some people reviewing suggesting edits *just don't care*.

I really don't see any useful purpose for having a way to search for tags without wikis. If you really care about tag wikis, look at the tags on questions that interest you. If you see new tags you haven't noticed before, just skim through them to see how exactly it's being used and whether you know enough to write a wiki for it. This is exactly what I do, especially here on Meta. I'd rather *wait* for a tag wiki from a legitimate user who *cares* about the tag wiki, than get a crap one now from someone who saw it in a list.

Comment: I can see this being useful for sites in beta, as part of site definition, but I share your concern about larger or graduated sites.

Comment: I concur with @MonicaCellio. This would be very useful for newer sites, even in the early post-beta stages.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm concerned, the most important purpose of a tag wiki is to identify when the tag should and shouldn't be used.

For example, is [case-when](/questions/tagged/case-when) to be used when you're talking about the SQL query, or when you're talking about control flow in Ruby?

Even a single sentence from an average user can suffice for this purpose.