# Search all tags with no tag wiki

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki, search

Is there a way I can search the Tags for tags with no tag wiki created yet?

Comment: Not really a search, but just visiting the New tags page will reveal quite a few: http://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new

Comment: @Bart Thanks! But it would be nice if there was a way to search more popular (5+ uses or so) tags for tags with no wikis.

Comment: Related feature request: [Searching for popular tags without tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152867/335251)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the Stack Exchange [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for this (specifically the `Tags` table).

Since I am so very helpful, I just wrote a query to do this: [Most common tags with missing wiki/excerpt](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/94917/most-common-tags-with-missing-wiki-excerpt). Feel free to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/94917) it to suit your needs. Note that since it is the Data Explorer, you're not accessing live data, but reasonably fresh for this type of query I should think.

Comment: Only thing is... I do not want tags that already have a wiki. If they have a wiki, but no excerpt, I am still not interested.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe Well, as I said, you can fork the query to make it do exactly what you want. Only finding missing wikis is a [trivial alteration](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/94920/most-common-tags-with-missing-wiki).

Comment: I prefer http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73048/wikiless-tags which shows the beginning of the excerpt or body when it's present. We both wrote essentially the same query, so we can't be doing it wrong, right? — LearnedSQLByWritingQueriesOnDataSE

Comment: @Gilles Wow yeah, that is really similar, LEFT JOINs and all. Although I'd like to know how your query returns 21402 results and mine 21401. Surely this must be witchcraft.

Comment: @lunboks My query finds [xmobar](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xmobar/info) and reports an empty excerpt and an empty body. At the time of the last dump, there was a suggested edit on the tag wiki excerpt and body but no accepted content yet. Which explains why the tag may be an edge case, but not why our near-identical queries would treat it differently.

Comment: Dosn't the query have a newer [optimized] version? Since it returns many tags that have existing wikis

Answer (score 8):

You can get close by googling for [+"There is no tag wiki for this tag" +site:http://stackoverflow.com/tags](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%2b%22There%20is%20no%20tag%20wiki%20for%20this%20tag%22+%2Bsite%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Ftags).

Comment: Interesting way of doing things. Will I get kicked out of SE sites if I use a non-SE search engine for tags? ;)

Comment: @BenjiWiebe, no, you're encouraged to use Google.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add somewhat to the current answers, the only way of currently doing this is, indeed the Data Explorer.

A while back I created a query to display those [tags, without wikis or excerpts, that you might be able to complete.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/87607/what-incomplete-tag-wikis-might-you-be-able-to-complete) Just put in the name of a tag which you know something about and all the related tags without wikis will be displayed in descending order by the number of questions tagged with that tag.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative way to find tags with no tag wiki is to visit the **NEW** tab on the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1&tab=new) as indicated by @Bart in the comments.

This will give you the latest added tags and those often doesn't come yet with a wiki or excerpt.

As you see how many questions already have the tag you can judge how valuable an excerpt/wiki would be. As a bonus you spot misspelled tags (retag those questions so the misspelled tag gets removed at 03:00 UTC) or tags that either should be synonyms of existing tags or simply be replaced by a better tag.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to search Tags using any Tag criteria, though at some point they may add the ability to search in favorite tags (see comments [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161743/13295)).